# How do I accomplish a 2D Isometric Projectile (3D) Rotation Effect

Tags: opengl, 3d, 2d, isometric, projectile

I am working on an isometric 2d game and one aspect of it will be units that shoot projectiles. If the projectiles are circular its not to bad. Just position the projectile in isometric space. But what if the projectile is long like a missile or an arrow?

I want to make it sort of look as if it is rotating or rather flying through 3d space not necessarily screen oriented. It doesn't need to be perfect since I am not doing this in 3d. I have a few options that I know of.

A) I could scale the image somehow based on the arc or rather the vector the projectile is traveling. I am actually not quite sure how the math for this would work though and how bad it may look.

B) I could rotate the actual sprite in 3D space. This method is tricky because there will be angles in which the sprite becomes invisible to the camera. This would be an undesired effect.

C) I could get sprites rendered for key rotations and display them. With this method I am not sure how rotating the sprites (normally) will affect the look.

Does anyone know of any good examples or ideas on solving this problem? What would be the best solution to render these sprites so that a projectile can launch from any point or land at any point on the isometric plane.

Comment: You are using trajectories for the projectile's path, right?

Comment: Yes the objects trajectory will be using 3D coords (the height of the projectile will be added to the y value). I am more concerned with rendering it so that arching arrows or missiles look right.

Answer (score -2):

Do a

```
While (projctl.traveling==1) {
    SetCurrentAVec(0,projctl);
    While (sprite.animVec.hasNext)
        SpinProjctl(1);
    (projctl.hit | projctl.miss ? projctl.traveling=0 : continue;
}
```